# Varnish Backend_health - Still sick

Tags: tomcat8, varnish

I'm using varnish-3.0.6-1 on one host and tomcat8 on another.
Tomcat is running fine but for some reason I can't get varnish backend to be healthy.

Here's my config:

```
probe healthcheck {
    .url = "/openam/";
    .timeout = 3 s;
    .interval = 10 s;
    .window = 3;
    .threshold = 2;
    .expected_response = 302;
}

backend am {
    .host = "<INTERNAL-IP>";
    .port = "8090";
    .probe = healthcheck;
}


sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        if (!client.ip ~ purgers) {
            error 405 "You are not permitted to PURGE";
        }

        return(lookup);
    }

    else if (req.http.host == "bla.domain.com" || req.http.host == "<EXTERNAL-IP>") {
        set req.backend = am;
    }

    else if (req.url ~ "\.(ico|gif|jpe?g|png|bmp|swf|js)$") {
        unset req.http.cookie;
        set req.backend = lighttpds;
    }

    else {
        set req.backend = apaches;
    }
}
```

It always shows:

```
Backend_health - am Still sick 4--X-R- 0 2 3 0.001956 0.000000 HTTP/1.1 302
```

telnet works fine to that host, the only thing that I can't figure it out is that curl returns 302 and that's because main page under 'openam' on tomcat redirects to another page.

```
$ curl -I http://<INTERNAL-IP>:8090/openam/
HTTP/1.1 302
Location: http://<INTERNAL-IP>:8090/openam/config/options.htm
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 12 Sep 2017 15:00:24 GMT
```

Is there a way to fix that problem?

Any advice appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, you're hitting on [this bug of Varnish 3](https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/issues/2069).

The reporter had 3.0.7 and that's the only one available now in packaged releases so you will likely have to build from sources.

So considering that, and Varnish 3 being quite old, I would rather recommend to upgrade to newer Varnish 4 or 5. (It's always easier to rewrite a few lines of VCL than maintaining something that was compiled from sources and the hassle associated with making sure it's always up-to-date).

Another obvious solution would be adjusting your app to send HTTP reason along the code, or perhaps point to the final redirect location which might (or not) already provide reason in HTTP status.

Check whether `curl -IL http://<INTERNAL-IP>:8090/openam/config/options.htm` provides a reason in the output.

If it's something like `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` and not just `HTTP/1.1 200` then simply update your health check to that URL (naturally adjust expected response code as well).